# How do I make the navbar stay within the parent div (hero image) regardless of screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I adjusted it based on my screen size, and I've tried using both relative and absolute positions for .navbar, but when I open it on my laptop the navbar content overflows the parent image, setting overflow to hidden doesn't fix the issue since i want it to stay over the bottom of the image at all times regardless of screen size. Here's the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Montinyek/4dbf5p9e/1/

````
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  font-family: Times, Times New Roman, serif;
}

.hero-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), url(./hero.jpg);
  height: 80%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #f2f2f2;
}


h1 {
  padding: 80px 60px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav-container {
  display: inline-block; 
  position: relative;
  top: 87%;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 70px; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 99vw;
  
}

.navbar a.main {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding-left: 47px;
  padding-right: 47px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  display: block; 
}


.navbar a.main:hover  {
  background-color: #ddd;
  transform: scale(1.3);
  color: black; 
}

.dropdown-content {
  visibility: none;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 64.6%;
  top: 80%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  min-width: 160px; 
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 14px 28px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 10px 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}


</style>
<body>


  <div class="hero-image">
    <div class="hero-text">
        <h1 style="font-size:50px">Welcome</h1></div>
        <div class="nav-container">
          <div class="navbar">
            <a class="main" href="#home">Home</a>
            <a class="main" href="#mission">Mission</a>
            <a class="main" href="#news">Contact</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a class="main" href="#news">More<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a style="color:rgb(238, 92, 92);" class="link" href="./index5.html">Gift</a>
                <a href="./index7.html">Travel</a>
                
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div></div>
      </div>

      
    
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well your issue, but I made some minor changes and got this result [demo](https://codepen.io/christian2033/pen/rNYPwWK)

HTML:

```
    <div class="hero-image">
      <div class="hero-text">
        <h1 style="font-size:50px">Welcome </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar">
         <a class="main" href="#home">Home</a>
         <a class="main" href="#mission">Mission</a>
         <a class="main" href="#news">Contact</a>
         <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="main" href="#news">More<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
               <a style="color:rgb(238, 92, 92);" class="link" href="./index5.html">Gift</a>
               <a href="./index7.html">Travel</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
        body,
html {
   height: 100vh;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: Times, Times New Roman, serif;
}

.hero-image {
   background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),
      url("https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.technistone.com%2Fen%2Fcolor%2Fstarlight-black&psig=AOvVaw3Ekck4Ncbtpa2vQdYYlN_V&ust=1646455838525000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCID6_o3Uq_YCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD");
   height: 80vh;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}

.hero-text {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   color: #f2f2f2;
}

.hero-text h1 {
   padding: 80px 60px;
   border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

.navbar {
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 120px;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   max-width: 100vw;
   width: 100%;
}

.navbar a.main {
   color: black;
   padding-left: 47px;
   padding-right: 47px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-radius: 5px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 20px;
   margin: 0px;
   transition: all 0.3s;
   display: block;
}

.navbar a.main:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
   transform: scale(1.3);
   color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
   visibility: none;
   opacity: 0;
   pointer-events: none;
   position: absolute;
   left: 64.6%;
   top: 80%;
   border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: black;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 14px 28px,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 10px 10px;
   z-index: 1;
   transition: all 0.5s;
}

.dropdown-content a {
   float: none;
   color: #ddd;
   padding: 12px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   transition: all 0.5s;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
   color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   display: block;
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
   pointer-events: auto;
}
```